# Populate column based on previous row with a twist

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm struggling with a Pandas problem. I have the following data.

```
+--------+------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+--------------+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
| symbol | side | status  | origQty | executedQty |     qty     | availableQty |   price    | boughtValue | soldValue  | dcaLevel |
+--------+------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+--------------+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
| DGDBTC | BUY  | FILLED  |   0.125 |  0.12500000 |  0.12500000 |   0.12500000 | 0.02000700 |  0.00250088 |            |          |
| DGDBTC | BUY  | FILLED  |   0.125 |  0.12500000 |  0.12500000 |   0.25000000 | 0.01960100 |  0.00245013 |            |          |
| DGDBTC | SELL | FILLED  |    0.25 |  0.25000000 | -0.25000000 |   0.00000000 | 0.02005900 |             | 0.00501475 |          |
| DGDBTC | BUY  | FILLED  |   0.113 |  0.11300000 |  0.11300000 |   0.11300000 | 0.02203000 |  0.00248939 |            |          |
| DGDBTC | BUY  | FILLED  |   0.113 |  0.11300000 |  0.11300000 |   0.22600000 | 0.02160300 |  0.00244114 |            |          |
| DGDBTC | BUY  | EXPIRED |   0.226 |  0.00000000 |  0.00000000 |              | 0.02125500 |             |            |          |
| DGDBTC | BUY  | PARTIAL |   0.226 |  0.15800000 |  0.15800000 |   0.38400000 | 0.02126100 |             |            |          |
| DGDBTC | SELL | EXPIRED |   0.384 |  0.00000000 |  0.00000000 |              | 0.02196600 |             |            |          |
| DGDBTC | SELL | EXPIRED |   0.384 |  0.00000000 |  0.00000000 |              | 0.02214300 |             |            |          |
| DGDBTC | SELL | EXPIRED |   0.384 |  0.00000000 |  0.00000000 |              | 0.02189900 |             |            |          |
| DGDBTC | BUY  | FILLED  |   0.384 |  0.38400000 |  0.38400000 |   0.76800000 | 0.02082900 |  0.00799834 |            |          |
| DGDBTC | BUY  | FILLED  |   0.768 |  0.76800000 |  0.76800000 |   1.53600000 | 0.01984300 |  0.01523942 |            |          |
| DGDBTC | SELL | EXPIRED |   1.536 |  0.00000000 |  0.00000000 |              | 0.02074400 |             |            |          |
| DGDBTC | SELL | EXPIRED |   1.536 |  0.00000000 |  0.00000000 |              | 0.02094100 |             |            |          |
| DGDBTC | SELL | EXPIRED |   1.536 |  0.00000000 |  0.00000000 |              | 0.02076800 |             |            |          |
| DGDBTC | SELL | PARTIAL |   1.536 |  0.30300000 | -0.30300000 |   1.23300000 | 0.02065000 |             |            |          |
| DGDBTC | SELL | FILLED  |   1.233 |  1.23300000 | -1.23300000 |   0.00000000 | 0.02070000 |             | 0.02552310 |          |
+--------+------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+--------------+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
```

This a subset of the data group by symbol. For each symbol I want to populate the last column with a value that complies with the following rules:

1. Each buy order (side=BUY) in a series has the value zero (0).
2. For each consecutive buy order the value is increased by
   one (1).
3. When a sell order (side=SELL) is reached it marks a new buy order serie.
4. Rows with status EXPIRED are skipped.

Example:

```
+--------+------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+--------------+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
| symbol | side | status  | origQty | executedQty |     qty     | availableQty |   price    | boughtValue | soldValue  | dcaLevel |
+--------+------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+--------------+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
| DGDBTC | BUY  | FILLED  |   0.125 |  0.12500000 |  0.12500000 |   0.12500000 | 0.02000700 |  0.00250088 |            |        0 |
| DGDBTC | BUY  | FILLED  |   0.125 |  0.12500000 |  0.12500000 |   0.25000000 | 0.01960100 |  0.00245013 |            |        1 |
| DGDBTC | SELL | FILLED  |    0.25 |  0.25000000 | -0.25000000 |   0.00000000 | 0.02005900 |             | 0.00501475 |          |
| DGDBTC | BUY  | FILLED  |   0.113 |  0.11300000 |  0.11300000 |   0.11300000 | 0.02203000 |  0.00248939 |            |        0 |
| DGDBTC | BUY  | FILLED  |   0.113 |  0.11300000 |  0.11300000 |   0.22600000 | 0.02160300 |  0.00244114 |            |        1 |
| DGDBTC | BUY  | EXPIRED |   0.226 |  0.00000000 |  0.00000000 |              | 0.02125500 |             |            |          |
| DGDBTC | BUY  | PARTIAL |   0.226 |  0.15800000 |  0.15800000 |   0.38400000 | 0.02126100 |             |            |        2 |
| DGDBTC | SELL | EXPIRED |   0.384 |  0.00000000 |  0.00000000 |              | 0.02196600 |             |            |          |
| DGDBTC | SELL | EXPIRED |   0.384 |  0.00000000 |  0.00000000 |              | 0.02214300 |             |            |          |
| DGDBTC | SELL | EXPIRED |   0.384 |  0.00000000 |  0.00000000 |              | 0.02189900 |             |            |          |
| DGDBTC | BUY  | FILLED  |   0.384 |  0.38400000 |  0.38400000 |   0.76800000 | 0.02082900 |  0.00799834 |            |        3 |
| DGDBTC | BUY  | FILLED  |   0.768 |  0.76800000 |  0.76800000 |   1.53600000 | 0.01984300 |  0.01523942 |            |        4 |
| DGDBTC | SELL | EXPIRED |   1.536 |  0.00000000 |  0.00000000 |              | 0.02074400 |             |            |          |
| DGDBTC | SELL | EXPIRED |   1.536 |  0.00000000 |  0.00000000 |              | 0.02094100 |             |            |          |
| DGDBTC | SELL | EXPIRED |   1.536 |  0.00000000 |  0.00000000 |              | 0.02076800 |             |            |          |
| DGDBTC | SELL | PARTIAL |   1.536 |  0.30300000 | -0.30300000 |   1.23300000 | 0.02065000 |             |            |          |
| DGDBTC | SELL | FILLED  |   1.233 |  1.23300000 | -1.23300000 |   0.00000000 | 0.02070000 |             | 0.02552310 |          |
+--------+------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+--------------+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
```

I have tried the following two ways.

```
merged_df['dcaLevel'] = merged_df[(merged_df['side'] == 'BUY') & (merged_df['status'].isin(['FILLED', 'PARTIAL']))].groupby(['symbol'])['dcaLevel'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(1) + 1)
```

This way throws an error.

```
merged_df['dcaLevel'] = merged_df[(merged_df['side'] == 'BUY') & (merged_df['status'].isin(['FILLED', 'PARTIAL']))].groupby(['symbol'])['dcaLevel'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x.shift(1) else x.shift(1) + 1)
```

I tried the following alternative approach.

```
symbol_df = merged_df.loc[merged_df['symbol'] == 'DGDBTC']
tmp_df = symbol_df[(symbol_df['side'] == 'BUY') & (symbol_df['status'].isin(['FILLED', 'PARTIAL']))]
tmp_df['dcaLevel'] = np.where(tmp_df['availableQty'] < tmp_df['availableQty'].shift(1), 0, tmp_df['dcaLevel'].shift(1) + 1)
```

It works on some rows and not on others and the first buy order in a serie remains NaN.

I have coded the following which does work, but I'm sure there is an easier way to do this with Pandas.

```
merged_df['dcaLevel'] = np.NaN
grouped = merged_df[merged_df['status'].isin(['FILLED', 'PARTIAL'])].groupby(['symbol'])
col_idx = merged_df.columns.get_loc('dcaLevel')
for name, group in grouped:
    first = True
    for index, row in group.iterrows():
        if row['side'] == 'SELL':
            first = True
            dca_level = np.NaN
        else:
            if first:
                first = False
                dca_level = 0
            else:
                dca_level = dca_level + 1
            merged_df.iloc[index, col_idx] = dca_level
merged_df[merged_df['symbol'] == 'DGDBTC']
```

I hope someone can help solve this problem.